# Where do I store small data items on a web site?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am writing a web site using asp.net mvc3 and in my website I want to have a page for setting capacity of a queue. this page is shared between some users. so I need to save this data somewhere which is reachable by all users. I do not like to store this value in Database because it is just a number and I prefer to save in another place.
I also tried storing in file but it is not a good idea too because it need permission setting.
is there any other place than files on server which let me do this?

Comment: Do you have an issue with storing numbers in a database ?

Comment: If it's enough to have this value for the lifetime of your application you could use a static variable with a default value. For a queue length this is may be enough, but I don't know what exactly you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Is it a dynamic value that changes via logic during runtime, or is it static and will never change once the application is started?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are going to have to **persist** it somewhere if you want it to stay around, either a flat file or database or something similar.

Other than that, you can **cache the value in memory** (session, static, or another caching scheme) so you aren't constantly reading it from a heavyweight store.  For example you could read it in on application start and then just use the in memory variable (writing it back to the disk when it changes).

Answer (score 1):

Just create a table `Settings` with two columns `Key` and `Value` and reuse it for other settings you may need in the future.

Your database is a good place for storing your data - ie. database backups will backup your settings as well.

The alternative is using Configuration Manager.

Answer (score 0):

NoSQL is a great option in this case, I think for this particular case Redis is a better fit, checkout Booksleeve from NuGet